# Exchangelib stream notification handle event

Tags: python, flask, exchangelib

So I am using the exchangelib fork from pull request #355 where stream notification is implemented. In my code i have gotten the conversation id and created a streaming subscription

```
def event_catch(self,account):
    id = ""
    ids = account.stream(account.calendar)
    for each in ids:
        print(each)
        id = each
    return account.events(each)
```

it returns the events object. what I am wondering is how do i handle the return data.

currently i have this but it crashes it.

```
event = data.event_catch(account)
while true:
    for each in event:
        print(each)
```

while i am able to store an event object as in.

```
event = data.event_catch(account)
```

I don't know what to do with it and perform an action when an event is returned.

Answer (score 0):

[Pull request #355](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/pull/355) is incomplete and untested, so you'll have to do some real work to get it working. The PR has useful comments to get you started :-)

Comment: Ya. I scrapped it and got bored. Nvm.

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned pull request was implemented in 2021 and the library now handles stream notifications. You can review [more here](https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/).